# How can I find a value in Tricore(TC1766) Arch?

Tags: ida, firmware, static-analysis

I recently work on Tricore Processor, but I have some problems.
With reading memory value. I do not know if I am right or not, but I think a part of flash memory copied to RAM and now in my algorithm used of RAM cell.
I have shown Code in below:

```
ld32.a          a15, [a0]-0x7BA4 ; a0 = 0xD00032E0
```

As you see, a15 is an address that point to a constant value(store in RAM or FLASH) and `a0` is the base address of RAM memory. To calculate `a15`, I subtract `a0` from `0x7BA4` but the result is 0xCFFFB73C. This Address is not a valid address of RAM.
**EDITED:**
I saw a freaky sentence in Tricore document.(I have shown in below)
[image]
As you see, `A[0]` can be protected by user application.
**Could it be protected in this case as well?**
**What is my wrong? What should I do? How can I get the correct value of `a15`?**

Comment: did you find where `a0` is initialized? Maybe it's not 0xD00032E0.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the address falls into the Scratchpad RAM region, so it’s probably initialized somewhere else. Try to look for references to C4000000 or C8000000, or other occurrences of `-0x7BA4` - maybe you’ll find the place where the variable is written to.

[image: Scratchpad RAM memory map]

Comment: ♦ Interesting. I've never given it much thought. I edited my question. Maybe it will help us to solve the problem.